# Click on link to open a new page, then open the accordion and scroll to the section with the ID

Tags: javascript, html, triggers, accordion

I'm trying to open another page and then open the Accordion and scroll to the section with the ID when the link is clicked. Any help would be greatly appreciated as i'm having no luck at the moment after searching for hours.

I'm guessing there is maybe something I could implement in my current Javascript code that could achieve this? Thanks

Anchor Tag -

```
<a href="/pagename#test">This is a Test</a>
```

Accordion -

```js
/** Class representing an accordion component. */
class Accordion {
  /**
   * Create an accordion component
   *
   * Accepts a container element which should contain a list of `details` and
   * `summary` elements
   *
   * @param   {String}  selector  The container element.
   */
  constructor(selector) {
    if (typeof selector !== "string") {
      console.error("Accordion selector must be a string");
      return;
    }
    this._container = document.querySelector(selector);
    this._container.addEventListener('click', (event) => this._toggle(event));
  }

  /**
   * Static method to close all `details` elements that are descendants of the
   * passed in container element.
   *
   * @param   {(HTMLElement|HTMLDocument)}  [elem=document]  The container
   */
  static closeAll(elem = document) {
    const opened = elem.querySelectorAll("details[open]");
    for (const elem of opened) {
      elem.removeAttribute("open");
    }
  }

  /** Private methods */

  /**
   * Toggle the accordion elements
   *
   * @param   {Event}  event  The triggering event object
   */
  _toggle(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const details = event.target.closest("details");

    if (details.hasAttribute("open")) {
      details.removeAttribute("open");
    } else {
      Accordion.closeAll(this._container);
      details.toggleAttribute("open");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <div class="box box">
      <div class="box-study box-study--content">
        Accordion Name
      </div>
      <div class="box-study box-study--image">
        <div class="studyicon">
          <img src="/iconimage.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </summary>
  <div class="inside themeGrey">
    <h3 id="test">Name of area I want to scroll too</h3>
  </div>
</details>
```

Comment: Please change the snippet I made to a [mcve] - Right now you are not creating the accordion. You need to look at location.hash and trigger that to open

Comment: Don't put `#` in your target HTML element id: `<h3 id="test">Name of area I want to scroll too</h3>`. In your URL, `#val` allows to say that you are targeting an HTML element having the id `val`.